# Do photons apply gravity?

Tags: gravity, photons, matter

Matter curves space time . as its mass grows the curvature of space-time grows. This curvature procedure of space time is to my opinion what slows down and prevents from mass to reach the speed of light. the bigger the mass the slower it goes with the same kinetic energy. Based on this logic ,since light always travels at the speed of light, I assume that it doesn't curve space time ( I am referring to photons travelling in open space time and not in a box where photons and matter interact). 
since Gamma rays can produce matter and anti-matter pairs .Since I assume that photons do not curve space-time ,but matter does ,then in order to conserve the original photonic anti-gravitational behavior, its anti-matter pair should have neutralizing anti-gravitational behavior. So if matter "pulls" towards it and slows time ,anti-matter "pushes" away from it and makes time run faster .this can explain why we cant see anti matter ,since it is spread in space stretching it in contrast to the matters gravitational pull. this can also explain the source of the "dark energy" .
This theory can be tested on anti-matter particles and photons in the future.
what do you think?

I know that the question if photons apply gravity was asked before and that there is not enough data today to answer this question and we are all based on General Relativity equations. what I am asking is ,assuming that photons in free space do not apply gravity, can we predict based on the fact that a Gamma photon can generate matter and anti-matter pairs that anti-matter applies anti gravity in order to keep the neutralizing zero gravity of the photon? this in my opinion is not a duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22876/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalence principle ensures all mass-energy gravitates, including that of photons; it all contributes to the stress tensor. Antimatter is unlikely to fall up (although some theorists would debate that).

Comment: May be the photons do not gravitate as the stress energy momentum tensor predicts. Since photonic gravitation is too small to measure today  this small wrong assumption was never noticed by measurements so far and was never contradicted. But since a photon can generate a matter and anti-matter pair ,this has a great impact on the gravitational anti-symmetry of matter and anti-matter. It's not that anti -matter falls up, it's that anti - matter spread uniformly through out  the void of space (and do not cluster like matter) and it is responsible to the mysterious  expansion of space.

Comment: @EranSinbar You can't just make up arbitrary modifications of theory based on "maybe this thing that's too small to measure isn't what everyone expects". There are very tight constraints on what sort of theory would make mathematical sense.

Comment: J.G , although it's a small modification ,too small to measure,to the 100 hundred years old theory  ,but it can lead to the understanding of huge questions like the missing anti matter and the mysterious  dark energy that was unknown 100 years ago when the theory was made . This modification can be tested in the future ,once photonic gravitation will be in the expected measurable scale. I predict that the tests will show that photons don't apply gravity and anti matter applies anti - gravity  based on the assumption that curvature of space and time dilation are conserved  in our universe.