# Loss of energy of a photon in gravitational field

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

I am interested in knowing about the relationship between a photon and a gravitational field. In this sense I refer to the loss that the former experiences when passing through the vicinity of a strong gravitational field, when a photon escapes from a gravitational field loses energy.

Light is well known when traveling long distances, its energy decreases which makes its frequency lower and also its wavelength is greater, which manifests as the redshift.

My question is: what has happened to the energy that the photon has lost?
Is it absorbed by the universe? .. or what do they mean when they say that the photon loses energy? Is there any interaction between the photon like boson and some other boson, suddenly, a gluon or the higgs field?

I would also like to know if you could contribute on some papers for future review. thanks

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/22876/does-a-photon-exert-a-gravitational-pull#22878

Answer (score 1):

A photon is a quantum mechanical entity/particle in the table of elementary particles in the [standard model of particle physics.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model). In the quantum field theory model we have of particles and interactions, the particles interact with the exchange of particles, and in order for the photon to lose energy it has to interact with something.

At present, quantization of gravity is only effective, not definitively modeled.There is no standard model for gravitational field and photon interactions. In what follows I am  giving an answer to your questions ,if the final theory of quantized gravity can be seen to lead to diagrams analogous to the diagrams of the other three forces. At the moment an effective gravitational quantum theory is used for cosmological problems, analogous to the one for the other forces.

In this effective gravity, one can have Feynman diagrams of the photon interacting with a gravitational field represented by the graviton, your "other boson".  In this [publication,](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.06298) there are diagrams for effective photon interactions with gravitons.

[image: phograv]

> FIG. 1: Feynman diagrams for the photon-graviton scattering, dashed lines represent gravitons, wavy lines represent photons.
>   Diagrams (a) and (b) give the amplitude M1, Eq. (24); diagram (c) gives the amplitude M2, Eq. (25); diagram (d) gives the
>   amplitude M3, Eq. (26).

Taking the simplest diagram (a) the energy lost (or gained: blue shift) from the photon in a strong gravitational field will be given to the field (or taken from), i.e. the mass source of that field.

The subject of [quantization of gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gravity) is a current research question. The red shift and blue shift are not treated at the quantum level, where  the photon belongs, but at the classical general relativity and electromagnetic level. We have to wait for the theory of quantized gravity to have the correct modeling.