# If photon is massless, then how can it interact with gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, photons, mass-energy

Photons are considered massless so how do they interact with gravity? According to Einstein Relativity, only curvature of space is responsible for bending of light rays. If so, and mass to mass interaction is useless, is considering gravitation a force pointless?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130552/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34352/2451 and links therein.

Comment: see my  relevant answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/525011/

Comment: @Qmechanic I think the duplicates talk about light (classical) not photons (quantum mechanical). the OP is talking of  "mass to mass interaction"  The answer  needs the concept of quantization of gravity and gravitons.which is not in the duplicates.

Comment: @annav I think the linked questions _are_ about photons. "How can gravity affect light?" explicitly mentions photons and them being massless, the other one mentions light being massless which is also only applicable if one thinks of light as photons. However, I agree that the answers are largely classical and ideally, IMO, they should mention photon-graviton vertices as you do in your linked answer. Maybe a version of your answer is needed on  ["How can gravity affect light?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130552/). :)