# If incoming photons increase the mass and gravity of a black hole are they then some kind of source of gravity?

Tags: energy, gravity, photons, mass, mass-energy

If incoming photons increase the mass and gravity of a black hole are they then some kind of source of gravity?I can not understand why equivalence of mass and energy lead as to say mass and energy are very similar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does a photon exert a gravitational pull?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22876/)

Comment: @NiharKarve Yes in a sense although I cannot grasp these photons trajectories as they should constantly move....