# If a photon is interacting with gravity why doesn't it posses gravitational field?

Tags: gravity, photons, mass, field-theory, models

If a photon is interacting with gravity why doesn't it posses gravitational field? Fermions interact with electromagnetic field because they themselves posses electromagnetic field. All inert masses have its own gravitational field and so interact with external gravity. Maybe the river model is a second pick but is it describing a photon as a vibration inside a fluid that sinks into a volume of mass causing gravity....

Comment: Why do you say that photons don't have gravity? All energy is a gravitational source. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22876/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes... but can be described the gravitational field of the photon in direction of photon propagation? Are these two velocities same(photon's by itself and of the gravitatinal field of the photon) ?